# Error when import pyplot from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have installed Anaconda 4.2.0 on Linux (64-bit) machine.
I import the whole matplotlib module, it works. But when I import pyplot from matplotlib like:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
```

Error occurs. It says

```
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

To my knowledge, the backend of pyplot has been fixed into PyQt5 in Anaconda 4.2. I have tried to import PyQt5. It is OK. I wonder why pyplot needs PyQt4. How can I fix this issue? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should open matplotlib package and find pyplot.py. 
Inside of it you should find the portion of code that import pyqt. Check if it's like this:

```
is_agg_backend = rcParams['backend'].endswith('Agg')
if 'wx' in sys.modules and not backend in ('WX', 'WXAgg'):
    import wx
    if wx.App.IsMainLoopRunning():
        rcParams['backend'] = 'wx' + 'Agg' * is_agg_backend
elif 'PyQt4.QtCore' in sys.modules and not backend == 'Qt4Agg':
    import PyQt4.QtGui
    if not PyQt4.QtGui.qApp.startingUp():
        # The mainloop is running.
        rcParams['backend'] = 'qt4Agg'
elif 'PyQt5.QtCore' in sys.modules and not backend == 'Qt5Agg':
    import PyQt5.QtWidgets
    if not PyQt5.QtWidgets.qApp.startingUp():
        # The mainloop is running.
        rcParams['backend'] = 'qt5Agg'
elif ('gtk' in sys.modules and
      backend not in ('GTK', 'GTKAgg', 'GTKCairo')):
    if 'gi' in sys.modules:
        from gi.repository import GObject
        ml = GObject.MainLoop
    else:
        import gobject
        ml = gobject.MainLoop
    if ml().is_running():
        rcParams['backend'] = 'gtk' + 'Agg' * is_agg_backend
elif 'Tkinter' in sys.modules and not backend == 'TkAgg':
    # import Tkinter
    pass  # what if anything do we need to do for tkinter?

_backend_selection()
```

This portion of code, check if you have at least one of these GUI Frameworks.

Let me know

Comment: Yes, that is the backend_detection(). Extractly same

Answer (score 0):

This topic is now old but is someone have the same problem, try to put this command in the cmd :

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

It works for me, I hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I already had this problem. I'd solved it by updating matplotlib:

```
pip(3) install --upgrade matplotlib
```

I'll add a tip.
You will often see people importing pyplot like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This is convenient when coding, shortening each line making a call to pyplot. Also, when browsing stackoverflow for answers, people will often use this format.